# Adding Intent Filter using manifest merger in Unity3d

Tags: android, android-intent, unity-game-engine, android-manifest

I'm having a hard time trying to merge the manifest from my plugin with the main manifest from Unity :(

The Unity Manifest

```
<activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
</activity>
```

My plugin Manifest

```
<activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
   <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="XXX"/>
          </action>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

My goal is to add this additional intent-filter to the ac, but it fails miserably with a

```
Trying to merge incompatible /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity
```

Adding tools:node="merge" or tools:node="replace" did not help either.

Any clue on how to add the intent ?
Thanks
D

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid merging through code but then you have to create a separate activity for your intent filter, which just calls the com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity

I just commited a intent helper utiliy I created once for this:
https://github.com/simon-heinen/aEx_unity/blob/master/aEx_IntentHelper/Plugins/Android/sources/IntentFilterActivity.java

```
public class IntentFilterActivity extends Activity {

private static final String LOG_TAG = IntentFilterActivity.class
        .getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final String gameObjectName = "IntentFilter";
    final String methodName = "OnIntentFilter";
    final String messageToSend = getIntent().getData().toString();

    /*
     * Get the main activity launch it and wait until the unity player is
     * ready to receive the URL via UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage()
     */
    String myOwnPackageName = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
    Intent mainLauncherIntent = getPackageManager()
            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(myOwnPackageName);
    startActivity(mainLauncherIntent);

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Will now wait until unity player is ready..");
            while (UnityPlayer.currentActivity == null) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Unity is ready, sending event: "
                    + gameObjectName + "." + methodName + "("
                    + messageToSend + ")");
            UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(gameObjectName, methodName,
                    messageToSend);
        }
    }.execute();

}
}
```

maybe you just use the complete https://github.com/simon-heinen/aEx_unity/tree/master/aEx_IntentHelper

I think this way is better then integrating it in the Unity activity itself, because you can reuse it in all your projects without modifing it at all ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can list all intents under one activity. So your manifest should look like this

```
<activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
             <data android:scheme="XXX"/>
         </action>
   </intent-filter> 
</activity>
```

Comment: Yes, this is the result I want to get eventually, but I can't (manually) create such as manifest: it needs to be the output of the merging of the 2 manifests  (cf. https://developer.android.com/tools/building/manifest-merge.html).

Comment: If you want to merge thought code, you should edit this as `XDocument`, this is how some plugins (like Unibill) updating manifests.  

But I'm sure I changed that mainly sometimes. You can try next:
1. Build game without plugin 
2. Take unity generated manifest in folder `/Temp/StagingArea/AndroidManifest.xml` 
3. Add your plugin permissions, and then put it to `Assets/Plugins/Android/AndroidManifest.xml` 
 
It's a bit dirty solution, but it worked for me.

Comment: Understood. I was hoping to avoid having to merge through code, and use instead the built-in merging mechanism. But if there's no other way, I will parse the manifest manually. Thanks.